# very very rougly sorting

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose we have an array ( int[] m ).

I need sort it... Result must be:

all items in the first half must be less or equal than any items in the second half.

how to do it?...

Comment: Is this homework? This sounds a lot like you've been asked to implement quicksort and are having trouble with the "partitioning" step.

Comment: Do you have a current attempt at code?  Do you have an attempt at pseudocode?

Comment: Btw, it couldn't hurt to accept more answers, so people are more likely to help you in the future.

Comment: no, it doesnt homework. if it is very easy for you maybe you explain how to do it?

Comment: @Karl, this is not equal to a "partinioning step" unless you can choose the pivot element so that it is equal to the median. A random pivot (as allowed by quicksort) will not fulfill the requirment.

Answer (score 6):

As Karl already mentioned in his comment, the task is equal to a *partinioning step* in the [quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) **with the exception** that you have to find the sample median first and use it as the pivot element.

Computing a [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Efficient_computation_of_the_sample_median) can be computed with O(n) operations, the partinioning step is linear too (O(n)), so the overall worst-case performance is still better than a full sorting (O(n log(n)).

The algorithm will go like this (standard methods need to be implemented):

```
public int[] roughSort(int[] input) {
  int pivot = findMedian(input);
  int[] result = partition(input, pivot);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
   Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i : array) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Sorting it in ascending order shall be ok for your case.

Comment: @mr V: yes but the proposed solution meets your specs in the easiest possible way (least code on your part). So +1 for this answer. If you _really_ want the sorting to be rough, do this, then just swap a few random elements in the top or bottom half :-)

Comment: for example: 51 4 10 19 -> 4 10 51 19

Comment: @mr. Vachovsky: But a fully sorted array still satisfies your requirements as stated, doesn't it? If there's something else you want, you should specify it.

Comment: I don't like this answer - I'm sure, the OP knows that `Arrays` provides a `sort` method and that a fully sorted array fullfills the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(2);
list.add(5);
list.add(1);
list.add(15);
list.add(55);
list.add(23);

Collections.sort(list);

int length = list.size();

List<Integer> list1 = list.subList(0, length/2);
List<Integer> list2 = list.subList(length/2, length);

Collections.shuffle(list1);
Collections.shuffle(list2);

List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
newList.addAll(list1);
newList.addAll(list2);

System.out.println(newList);
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: To my opinion, that's even worse than Mohamed's answer. He didn't ask for a random distribution in the sublist. My guess is that he wants something with better performance than a fully blown sort.

Comment: HARD!!!!!! NO!!!!! ok, suppose, that array contains many items, you are suggesting sort this array instead of do roughly sort?! Full sorting is required time more than roughly sorting.

Comment: @mr. Vachovsky - Now I know that performance is a requirement - please edit your question to add a clarification.